# How do I place a static image behind my menu bar in my website?

Tags: css, padding, linear-gradients

I couldn't find appropriate answer for it in anywhere. Instead, I created a simple menu bar using linear-gradient tag. So, I am really stuck right now and no matter how much I try I cannot make it work.

```
#navigation li
        {
            margin:auto;
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            background-color:orange;
        }

        #navigation li a
        {           
            margin-left:150;
            float:left;
            width:8.3em;
            padding:9px;
            text-decoration:none;
            background:-webkit-linear-gradient(chocolate, orange);
            background:linear-gradient(chocolate, orange);
            color:black;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-size:15px;
            font-weight:bold;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        #navigation li a:hover
        {
            color:brown;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
```

Comment: Can you give a bette explanation of what you're trying to do? I think i got it but you should also give us more code. Tip: Give a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) link with the css **and** html code so we can help you.

Comment: Put background: url(image-source-path) 0 0 no-repeat; in css where you wanna have image.